# How to remove the rows with the same code when a cell is equal with a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find a way to remove all rows that the value of the first column is same AND the value of 3 row is equal with 1(or whatever value decide)

How i understand it is IF column values are equal and one of the values of this rows that they have column one equal has the value 1 don't show me nothing.

```
    COLUMN1          COLUMN2         COLUMN3 
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     NULL         Slot - Arrival
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     NULL         Fuel - Departure
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     NULL         Slot - Departure
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     NULL         Passenger - Newspaper
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     NULL         Slot - Dead Head Arrival
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     NULL         Slot - Dead Head Departure
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     FHA 1115z    Handling Request - Arrival
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     FHA 0945z    Handling Request - Departure
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     NULL         Fuel - Arrival
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     NULL         GenDec EGGP
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     NULL         GenDec LFMN
VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP     NULL         1 HANDLING invoice checked
VTV745 LFMT->LEBB     NULL         Fuel - Departure
VTV745 LFMT->LEBB     Fpp 0940z    Handling Request - Arrival
VTV745 LFMT->LEBB     NULL         Billing Confirmed
VTV745 LFMT->LEBB     NULL         Contract Signed
VTV745 LFMT->LEBB     FPP 0800z    Handling Request - Departure
VTV745 LFMT->LEBB     NULL         Fuel - Arrival
VTV745 LEBB->LFMT     NULL         Fuel - Departure
VTV745 LEBB->LFMT     FPP 1620z    Handling Request - Arrival
VTV745 LEBB->LFMT     fpp  1500z   Handling Request - Departure
VTV745 LEBB->LFMT     fuel relea   Fuel - Arrival
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) I don't understand "the value of 6 row is equal with 1", especially because there are no "1"s in the table. (3) What is the output/results based on your data.

Comment: Add columns name too

Comment: This is a query that shows me all the data for a table. I want to show me only the values that the do not have value 1 Handling that is on column 3. In this case we have VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP that actualy has the value 1 Handling so i have to find a way to remove also all the other rows that the have VFP193 LFQQ->EGGP.

Comment: Ylli Frroku, Do you mean that wherever there is "1 HANDLING invoice checked" in column 3, you want to remove that row and all rows which have same value as Column1 of that row??

Comment: Yes exactly this

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from TableName Where Column1 in (
select Column1 from TableName where Column3 = '1 HANDLING invoice checked'
)
```

Comment: Does this help Ylli Frroku?

Comment: this deletes i want just to run the query not to delete the data

Comment: @YlliFrroku, coz you asked ***"How to remove the rows..."***

Comment: Yeah right...you said, you wanted to delete. Anyways edited answer shows how to query...

Comment: This query is very redundant. you can just use the inner `SELECT`. no need to nest it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [`LIKE`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-like-clause.htm):

Something like this?

`SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE COLUMN3 LIKE '%1 HANDLING%'`

The above query means - select all records which contains '1 HANDLING' in its Column3.

Comment: yes but this one selects only one row no also the other rows that they have the same column1 value